# How to wait until navigation is completed in Selenium / Puppeteer tests of Blazor app

Tags: selenium, puppeteer, blazor, ui-automation, blazor-server-side

I have Blazor server application with a standard router.

I would like to write a Selenium UI automation, that navigates to specific URL and waits until a page is rendered.

For now I just check for an element that is specific to that page and wait until it is displayed:

```
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("/"); //initial load
...
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("/counter"); //navigate async
var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElementsByCssSelector(...).Count == 1)
```

Is there a better, more generic way that finding expected element on page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other ExpectedConditions like `ElementIsVisible`() or `ElementToBeClickable`()

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("your selector")));
```

OR

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("your selector")));
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to find page specific element. I would like to wait until navigation is completed without knowing what elements are expected on the page

Comment: I think it's more reliable to wait for a particular element, but in Puppeteer you can use `networkidle0` or `networkidle2` to wait after navigation https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions